# Drawer icon's ripple on the toolbar is too big

Tags: android, toolbar, drawer, ripple

Can't find a way to make drawer icon's size smaller. It is normal starting on the API 24, so the problem is in Marshmallow. Almost every app you will find is that way. Any ideas how to make it smaller?

Comment: have you found the answer to this?

Comment: No, the problem wasn't so crucial at the moment and it has been forgotten.